# Implementing TouchID Verification fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a TouchID setting that would allow users to authenticate through TouchID if that option is on, but I can't seem to get it to work. After some testing, the app breaks. It cannot be executed in Simulator with the following code being highlighted in red:
[image]

After getting this error, even Undoing every change, it still displays that and I have to resort to a backup of the whole project folder.

My code that handles the Touch ID authentication:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("TouchID"){
let myContext = LAContext()
var authError: NSError?
// Set the reason string that will appear on the authentication alert.
let myReasonString = "String explaining why app needs authentication"
if myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
    [myContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: myReasonString, reply: { (success: Bool, evalPolicyError: NSError?) -> Void in

        if success {
            // User authenticated successfully
        } else {
            // Authenticate failed
        }
    })]
} else{
    // Could not evaluate policy; check authError
}
}
```

The part of the page that handles the switch:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var TouchID: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.restoreSwitchesStates();
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TableViewController.saveSwitchesStates), name: "kSaveSwitchesStatesNotification", object: nil);
}



func saveSwitchesStates() {
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(TouchID!.on, forKey: "TouchID");
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
    }

    func restoreSwitchesStates() {
        TouchID!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("TouchID");

    }
```

Comment: You need to get the full exception from the console,

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint